# Proxy server does not get response from server

Tags: java, debugging, proxy-server

This is my first time making a web server. I want to create a proxy server. For now, I'm setting the server to "www.google.com" and not doing any parsing of HTTP requests.

I run ProxyServer on command line, then I call the server using "telnet server_name 5000" on another command line window, followed by "GET / HTTP/1.1".

Everything works until the while loop that handles the server's response. Nothing gets printed out. Why is that so?

All help appreciated.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ProxyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int proxyServerPortNumber = 5000;
    String hostName = "www.google.com";
    int portNumber = 80;


    try {
        // SERVER
        // Open socket connection and bind it to proxyServerPortNumber
        ServerSocket serverSocket =
            new ServerSocket(proxyServerPortNumber);

        // Listen and accept request
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
        System.out.println("client request accepted");

        // send to client socket
        PrintWriter sendToClient =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);     

        // get from client socket           
        BufferedReader getFromClient = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        // CLIENT
        // open socket connection
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

        // send to server
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // get from server
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));


        String clientRequest;
        // clientRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
        while ((clientRequest = getFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("in while loop");
            System.out.println(clientRequest);

            out.println(clientRequest); // send to server
            System.out.println("sent to server");

            //Get response from server
             String response;
             while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) // no response why?
            {
                sendToClient.println("echo: " + response);
                System.out.println("echo:" + response);
            }    
        } // end while loop


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash in your HTTP request should be a forward slash.

Comment: Oh I realized my description is inconsistent with my code. Let me test it again.

Comment: Ok I fixed the request and the server still returns nothing

Comment: Maybe you should see if your client code can connect without use of the proxy server.